# What is this thread like thing coming out of my car tyre?

Tags: tires

What is this rubbery thread like thing hanging out of my tyre?
Is it safe? Can I cut it off using a blade or else just stick it to the tyre using gum?
[image: tyre photo]

Comment: Gum certainly won't be reliable.  Is it part of the tire, sliced nearly off perhaps? The picture is unclear.

Comment: It's difficult to tell from the picture but it looks similar to a rope style, don't know the technical name, tire patch. These are pushed in from the outside and then trimmed down. If it is a patch though it should be somewhat hard and stiff like the tire rubber.

Comment: Yes, indeed it is hard and stiff.

Comment: I tried adding a high res image but the website didn't allow asking me to upload a smaller size image.